# externalTrafficPolicy: local with ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We want to access only local services via Ingress using K3S (1.23) and Traefik.

We have an NGINX gateway running as a DaemonSet on all nodes, exposed as a NodePort 30123 called `gateway` with `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`. When we ping `https://node1:30123` we consistently get only a local pod from the nginx instance on node1. ✔

We also have our Ingress Controller Traefik running as a DaemonSet exposed as a NodePort 30999 with `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`. When we hit `https://node1:30999` we get a load-balanced answer ❌‍♂️:

```
answer from node1
answer from node2
answer from node1
answer from node3
etc
```

How can we ensure that `https://node1:30999` only gets routed to local pods?

### Ingress Resource

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: node1
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: gateway
            port:
              number: 8443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: node2
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: gateway
            port:
              number: 8443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - node1
    - node2
    secretName: tls-secret
```

### Gateway Service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: gateway
spec:
  clusterIP: ***
  clusterIPs:
  - ***
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: https
    nodePort: 30123
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: gateway
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

The reason we want only local traffic is because Kubernetes is too slow at evicting pods/endpoints from a service when a node goes down. It continues to send traffic to dead nodes/pods for minutes after a node disappears. We use an external load balancer with active health checks every 2s to avoid this problem. However, evern if our LB targets only healthy nodes, Kubernetes "Services" still have invalid endpoints and round-robin traffic into nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be due to the fact that you are running traefic as a daemonset which behaves like a shared daemon running on all nodes and every node will then apply the local traffic policy to the request.

So basically running the Ingress Controller as a daemonset and setting the controllers service traffic Policy to Local will result in some behavior that equals the Cluster Policy.

Further the idea of the Ingress Controller is to route the traffic to a specific service in the cluster. Accessing a node directly on the Ingress-Controller Service Port will not trigger any forwarding rules. You should instead create a Ingress Resource that maps some existing service (Nginx-test-pod). This services traffic policy must then be set to "Local" too to see the real SourceIP in the services log.